# How do I convert the .dat gobble-di-gook into something intelligible?

Tags: type-conversion

I'm wondering how/if one converts a .dat file into something modifiable and readable. Any info would vastly help. For example a code snippet, program, or just general information.

Comment: https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-a-dat-file-2620550 DAT is a generic file extension; you need to give us context.

Comment: well, i'm trying to edit a game's .dat file, it would be a text file.

Comment: What game? .dat isn’t a specific format, so it depends on the game

Answer (score 0):

I generally use hexdump, but it's not available for all operating systems, and probably wouldn't help you more than what you're looking at now.

As already pointed out in comments, DAT is a generic extension used to signify a (usually proprietary) binary format -- other than not being text, there's no commonality.  You need to know what format it's in before you can have any hope of translating it into something legible by humans.

All we "know" from the extension is that the file is NOT line-based text -- and that could be wrong.

Comment: it's some type of text file, so it should convert nicely.

Comment: Perhaps ... but given only the file extension, we can say nothing for sure about the format.